# A database that collects logs from other databases?

Tags: database, postgresql

Is there any way in the postgres configuration file so that the database receives logs from other databases? The point is to have a database that only serves to collect logs. How can you configure such bases?

Comment: PostgreSQL has the SQL/MED standard from ANSI it is Management of External Data.. ( https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL/MED ) where you can query other DMBS from PostgreSQL.

Comment: What kind of "logs" are you talking about? If those are "application logs" (e.g. an Apache access log or something similar), then you can use an ETL tool to import that data into a Postgres database.

Comment: What type of logs? For example, an erroneous query. I want to have a database that will collect such logs from other databases and then be able to display them in the table by query.